# CSS Media Query in cm Possible? -OR- How to easily create specific CSS for ANY smart phone?

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

**This is not a duplicate question, because I don't want to target the iPhone 6 specifically, I want to target *ALL smart phones and mini tablets*, *icluding* the iPhone 6, 7, 8, etc and Android, etc**

---

I'm trying to find out a useful CSS media query to detect smart phones.
So, I was thinking, the following would fit perfectly since the screen resolution in px on an iPhone 6 is almost the same as the one from a desktop screen with a pixel ratio of 1:

```css
@media (max-device-width:16cm){ /* I need the PHYSICAL device width */
  ...
}
```

However, I'm not sure if this translates interally ALWAYS to 529.2px (1cm == 37.8px) or does it really respect the **actual device width in cm** of the hardware?

---

**Because, in my opinion, what really matters is the *physical space available*, and I don't care at all how many pixels there are to represent this area in order to decide how much content I want to show.**

Comment: Well you can't really use centimeters in css because on some devices the pixels are further apart from each other.

Comment: @Alagaros This is what I was afraid of. Logically, it makes sense to use centimeters, but it probably doesn't produce the expected outcome. So what would be a better media query to decet smart phones?

Comment: @DominicTobias Yes and no. I would like to detect ALL smart phones, including iPhone 6 - not just this one.

Comment: Well what you could do is create some algorithm using the DPI (density per pixel) more information on that here http://stackoverflow.com/a/8488316/3571997

Comment: Thank you, @Alagaros. So in other words, use JavaScript, detect the pixel ratio, and load the appropriate CSS and ignore the (useless) media css query?

Comment: Yes, that is how I would do it :)

Comment: @Alagaros Alright, I think this is what I'm going to do! I like it :)

Comment: What's wrong with using the width? Consider < 768px all mobile. http://www.lexus.ca is a good example of responsive website

Comment: @Huangism Well, the iPhone 6 Plus for example has a 1920-by-1080-pixel resolution. So this is exactly not <768px.

Comment: @SimonFerndriger that's not the width in the browser, view lexus.ca on iphone 6+ and you get the mobile version. We also have `<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, width=device-width" />` Here look for yourself http://viewportsizes.com/?filter=iphone view port width is what matters

Answer (score 2):

You can't use centimeters because some devices have their pixels further apart.

However what you could do is check the device's pixel density. Here is how you can use a media query with the pixel density.

```
@media all and (min-resolution: 150dpi) 
{
   body 
   {
      // do something
   }
}
```

The second way would involve some JavaScript as described [here](https://mobilewidgetdev.wordpress.com/2010/07/20/how-to-really-cope-with-varying-screen-sizes-and-pixel-resolutions-in-vodafone-widgets/).

Comment: OK, thank you. I think this is the best CSS solution so far. However, this would still include high resolution desktop displays...

Comment: Isn't it ironic, that something so simple to grasp, is probably impossible for CSS (CSS needs so much improvement in general in my opinion)?

Comment: Yeah I agree, still trying to think about a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Media query in pixels is all you need. Screen resolution and viewport width are 2 different things.

You can check http://viewportsizes.com/?filter=iphone for view port width. The link has the iphone filter but you can remove it to look at other phones.

I usually use 768px as a cut of point. Anything above or equal to 768 I use a desktop view and anything below I use a mobile layout. It's not device-dependent, you are simply checking the view port width or browser width to determine what should be shown.

http://www.lexus.ca uses this cut off point, I am just linking this to give you an example