# Shake event on mobile web apps

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, dom-events, shake

I was wondering of there is a way to trigger the shake event within a mobile web app?

--EDIT---
Without using Phonegap.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't google much did you? :)

[Phonegap - Handling Shake Events](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/16494783/Handling%20Shake%20Events)

edit: Read this Stackoverflow Article. Dont get distracted by the "Phonegap" in the title - it works without it. As a summary: You can invoke Java Code with Javascript and would invoke the native Accelerometer from your web code. [Invoking Java Code with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727763/communication-between-android-java-and-phonegap-javascript)

Comment: I forgot to say that phonegap was not an option ;)

Answer (score 0):

Shake.js is a custom 'shake' event JavaScript plugin for mobile web browsers using device accelerometer.  Your web browser must support the devicemotion event for this plugin to work.  Shake.js uses built-in feature detection to determine if it can run in your web browser.  It will terminate silently on non-supporting browsers.

You might want to check this out: http://functionn.blogspot.com/2012/03/shakejs-custom-shake-event-javascript.html