# How to detect android pinch zoom in javascript

Tags: javascript, android

I would like to know if there's any way to detect that a pinch zoom event has taken place. I could achieve it by using this event binding for iOS

```
$(document).bind('gesturechange',function(event){
     zoomAdjust();
});
```

Is there any such event for android devices?

Comment: Have you tried that in Android? Usually the events are the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9818336/jquery-android-pinch-zoom

Comment: @ThinkingStiff yes I tried that in android, didn't work

Comment: any reason for downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a great js ready for this called [Hammer JS](http://eightmedia.github.com/hammer.js/)

Comment: thanks that is a great way to detect plenty of the android events. However I went ahead with `scroll` event, as page is pinch zoomed it also gets scrolled.

Comment: This is not an answer, more of a comment, and it is a whole library, which is an overkill for a simple detection as asked in the question. :/

Answer (score 1):

There is also another great jQuery plugin called [TouchSwipe](http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/touchSwipe/demos/).