# Pinch/zoom within a div but not whole page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, jquery-mobile

Is it possible to enable pinching/zooming of a specific div on a page?  I don't want to pinch/zoom the entire page, just a specific element.

I am using jQuery, jQuery Mobile and viewing the project on an iPad.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11517086/472495

Comment: Interesting (and also found with a ten-second search engine search): https://forum.jquery.com/topic/detect-pinch-zoom-on-an-image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Zoomooz](http://jaukia.github.io/zoomooz/). It's a jQuery library which is very interesting:

Comment: Zoomooz does not support multi-touch pinching events. Its only a library for zooming into elements on a page, but has no support for pinching behavior, so far as I can see in the documentation.