# Call Native Android Java Code from HTML5/JavaScript using PhoneGap Plugins (and implement async callbacks)

Tags: android, web-services, cordova, native-code

I want to get web service data using java and pass it to index.html file using java script
I have a web service that return xml format data. i want to create android app using phone gap. and use this webservice.

Now i want create a function in java file that get data from webservice and return in html page. and java function call with javascript.

have any one any idea....

Comment: Here's a nice explaination:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/2737388/477176