# How can I run java code within phonegap / cordova?

Tags: android, cordova

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Communication between Android Java and Phonegap Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727763/communication-between-android-java-and-phonegap-javascript)

I have some code I would like to run whenever the user presses a button within my Phonegap index.html interface

// toggle airplane mode

```
  Settings.System.putInt(
  context.getContentResolver(),
  Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, isEnabled ? 0 : 1);
```

// Post an intent to reload

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
intent.putExtra("state", !isEnabled);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

I would like to launch that code whenever a button is pressed. Maybe make a javascript function somehow that runs java code (if possible), so I can make something like

```
    <input type="submit" onlick="reconnect();" value="Reconnect to Cell Tower">
```

I am using Cordova 1.9.0

Comment: just search for it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727763/communication-between-android-java-and-phonegap-javascript

Comment: I'm fairly new to android development. I do not have any knowledge of java. I also don't know if that would be compatible with 1.9.0. Certainly there is probably a simpler way to do this.

Comment: if that solution is complicated for you you have to rebuild your know-how because the answer to that question is really easy to apply for a Java programmer, it's also fairly easy in its own concept.

Answer (score 1):

Just implement corrodovaInterface in your main activity like this..

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements CordovaInterface, OnClickListener {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
CordovaWebView cwv;
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    cwv = (CordovaWebView) findViewById(R.id.webContent);    
    cwv.loadUrl("your index file");
    Button btnSearch = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
    btnSearch.setOnClickListener(this);
}

    public void onClick(View v) {
     //your code goes here...
}
```

you may need to import

```
import org.apache.cordova.*;
import org.apache.cordova.api.CordovaInterface;
import org.apache.cordova.api.IPlugin;
```

Thanks.

Comment: THanks for your help. How would I call upon it in the index.html file?

Comment: cwv.loadUrl("your index file"); here you can set your index.html file

Comment: cwv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");   use this