# Phonegap - Passing String URL Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() to the HTML to access local xml file

Tags: android, cordova

I am using phonegap to build a little android app. I need to get the data from a locally stored file. I have created a folder and have the xml file in there and can load it and see it when the app starts via:

```
String url = "file:///" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + File.separator + "DV/emp.xml";
super.loadUrl(url, 500);
```

I would like to call this within the `HTML` file found in `assets/www`.

How can I pass this string `URL` variable to my html file?

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer, but would like others to respond if you'd be so inclined.

[Communication between Android Java and Phonegap Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727763/communication-between-android-java-and-phonegap-javascript)