# PhoneGap use java class on android and iOS

Tags: java, android, ios

Can I use the same java class in phonegap for Android and iOS ?

e.g. This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727763/communication-between-android-java-and-phonegap-javascript) will be work on iOS too ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use Java on iOS at all.

You'd have to create Objective-C code to do the same thing as your Java class, and if they provide the same interface to Phonegap, at least the Javascript code can be shared.

Comment: is this problem only affects iOS ?? java code will be work on windows mobile or blackberry?

Answer (score 0):

Now java can be used on iOS, please check this [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/overview/adf-mobile-096323.html).
Hope the samples will answer your question.