# Calling native function on android using Phonegap HTML5

Tags: android, cordova, native

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Communication between Android Java and Phonegap Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727763/communication-between-android-java-and-phonegap-javascript)

I am just starting to develop using Phonegap and Android..
I would like to know, 
if I have a button on the HTML page, would that button be able to call a native function?
For instance lets say i want the button to open up the calendar and pass variables from the html form

I am total newbie when it comes to Android native and HTML5

Please help

Comment: Have you check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2737388/1265724)

Answer (score 1):

You basically need to call a javascript code on button click and write your own phonegap plugin to call native functionality.

[Phonegap Android plugin development](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_plugin-development_android_index.md.html#Developing%20a%20Plugin%20on%20Android)

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible you can call java codes from java script in phonegap.see [here](http://www.speakingcode.com/2012/05/29/call-native-android-java-code-from-html5javascript-using-phonegap-plugins-and-implement-async-callbacks/)