# From PhoneGap to call the JS function

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I saw that you can call from JS to function of PhoneGap on the following link:

[Communication between Android Java and Phonegap Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727763/communication-between-android-java-and-phonegap-javascript)

My question is if you can in the **opposite** way?

From PhoneGap to call the JS function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I were you, I would read this [tutorial](http://ganeshtiwaridotcomdotnp.blogspot.se/2011/09/android-javascriptinterface-tutorial.html) on how to implement a JavaScript interface on Android,  and after this you should be able to call a JavaScript functions either way.

for example from your code: `webViewName.loadUrl("javascript:somemethod()");`

I believe you can implement this behavior in PhoneGap. Tell me if i'm wrong!

That's what i think off the top of my head. :)

Answer (score 1):

in android, the DroidGap class(one which is base class for activity for a phonegap app) provides method "sendJavascript()" to execute javascript. this methods is available for activity extending the DroidGap class, something like this -

```
     public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        MainActivity.this.sendJavascript("var myInt=10;");
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
}
```

Comment: And I can run this way a function of JS? Or is it just sending parameters?

Comment: you can make a function call this way, basically any valid javascript statment can be executed.