# How to use java classes in phonegap with javascript in android application?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I need to get external storage location path, for that have in android `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` but how can i use this in phonegap with javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For use java classes in `PhoneGap` you should take a look over here : [Communication between Android Java and Phonegap Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727763/communication-between-android-java-and-phonegap-javascript), it will definitely hep you

Comment: public class storage {
 String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
 return state;
}

but error like this syntax error on token return invalid type..

Comment: This is not the way to write class in java, please check link again and follow procedure accordingly

Comment: Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() working for me, but its returns internal sdcard path, but i need to get external sdcard path