# Accessing android Google Account Id /username via phonegap?

Tags: android, cordova

Please can anybody tell me how to access Google account details in android phone via phone gap?
I have searched a lot on internet but i am not getting the solution for this.
Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion would be to write the code for getting the Google Account info in Android Java like so:

http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/auth.html

And then create a JS interface to communicate with your webview to pass it the credentials like so:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2737388/1062787

Comment: As suggested by Matthew, a plugin is build to suit the need can be found [here](https://github.com/bvarga/GetAccountsPlugin/blob/master/plugin.xml)