# Access phone alarm (native resources)using html5 (Reminder app)

Tags: android, html, cordova, phonegap-plugins

These are my technologies,

1. HTML5
2. Jquery mobile, Jquery, Java Script
3. Css
4. Cordova

We are developing app using HTML 5 and we need to access phone (Android,iPhone,Windows Phone) resources, such as alarm (to create reminder).
Questions,

1. Can we access native resources of mobile phones through this technologies ?
2. Do we need different coding to access different mobile operating systems ?
3. What are the pros and cons of this method ?
4. what is the Best method of doing this ?
5. Any suggestions ?

   ---

Sample code or examples for access Android, Iphone and Windows phone 8 alarm manager  through javascript?

---

Did any one use this [Background Service Plugin](https://github.com/Red-Folder/bgs-core/issues/5) for this task?

I asked question regarding this [use for access alarm manager](https://github.com/Red-Folder/bgs-core/issues/5)

do any one have sample code or give me a step by step guidance, how to use this for access Android alarm manager ?

---

I try to access native code through java script like [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727763/communication-between-android-java-and-phonegap-javascript/22014440#22014440) but it's not working.

When i clicked the button;

1. in eclipse logcat; under cordova tag,

Uncaught TypeError:Object [object Object] has no method 'getTelephoneNumber'

2. in eclipse logcat; under chromium tag,

[INDO:CONSOLE(22)]"Uncaught TypeError:Object [object Object] has no method 'getTelephoneNumber'", source: file:///android_asset/www/index.html (22)

my phonegap version is 2.7.0 and Emulator API level 19. what is the problem in here ? did i miss anything ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a long running process i manage to come up with solution to the android devices.

1. Access native code using [javascript is possible](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html)
2. Using javascript interface raise a threat of xss vulnerability, but in Latest API Level 19 eliminated this.

**Let the code speak;** MainActivity code first

```java
@SuppressLint({ "JavascriptInterface", "SetJavaScriptEnabled" })
public class MainActivity extends DroidGap
```

1. `onCreate` method code

```java
super.init();
WebView webView = new WebView(this);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

// Add these lines according to your requirements
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
webView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
webView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
//webView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webView.setClickable(true);
```

2. To complete next step you need to have `Reminder` class with in your `MainActivity` class and what ever html file in your assets folder. In my case i have `Login.html` in `assets/www/Phone/Login.html`

```java
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new Reminder(this), "Reminder");
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/Phone/Login.html");
setContentView(webView);
```

3. Here is my `Reminder` class and its constructor

```java
public class Reminder {
    private Context con;

    public Reminder(Context con){
        this.con=con;
    }
}
```

4. `ReminderReceiver` class

```java
public class ReminderReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    // Vibrator object
    public Vibrator vibrator;
    long[] pattern = { 0L, 250L, 200L, 250L, 200L, 250L, 200L, 250L, 200L, 250L, 200L, 250L, 200L, 250L, 200L };

    // Ringtone object
    Uri ringT;
    Ringtone ringTone;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String remindText = intent.getStringExtra("text");
        int receiverID = intent.getIntExtra("AlrmId", 0);

        // Notification creation
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_popup_reminder)
                .setContentTitle("Reminder").setContentText(remindText);

        // Create vibrator pattern
        vibrator = (Vibrator) context
                .getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vibrator.vibrate(pattern, -1);// No repetition

        // Notification tone creation and play
        ringT = RingtoneManager
                .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        ringTone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, ringT);
        ringTone.play();

        // Create toast and show on center of the screen
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, remindText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        toast.show();

        // Show status bar notification
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(receiverID, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

5. Method that can call through JavaScript and responsible to add Alarm object into System Alarm Manager. In Reminder class

```java
@JavascriptInterface
public void addReminder(int mYear, int mMonth, int mDay, int mHour, int mMinute) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

    // set Reminder time and date into calendar object
    c.set(Calendar.YEAR, mYear);
    c.set(Calendar.MONTH, mMonth); // Don't use exact numeric value of the month, use one minus. Ex: April => 3
    c.set(Calendar.DATE, mDay);
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, mHour);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mMinute);
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    // Unique Alarm ID creation
    int alrmId = 0;
    alrmId = Integer.parseInt(mMonth + "" + mDay + "" + mHour + "" + mMinute);
    
    // Alarm task creation
    Intent in = new Intent(con, ReminderReceiver.class);
    in.putExtra("text", "You have a Reminder!");
    in.putExtra("AlrmId", alrmId);

    PendingIntent pi;

    pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(con, alrmId, in, 0);

    AlarmManager am;

    am = (AlarmManager) (con.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE));
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
}
```

6. Now, you need to edit your `Android Manifest.xml`,

   - set permissions `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />` and
   - register `ReminderReceiver` class, add this lines with in `<application> </application>` tag `<receiver android:name=".ReminderReceiver"></receiver>`.
7. Finally in your html file add button, add javascript function, call it in button click event and inside of that function call `addReminder` method

```js
function test() {
    Reminder.addReminder(2014, 3, 4, 12, 30);
}
```

**Hope this answer will help who trying to using Native function of Android phone while developing through Phonegap.**

Answer (score 1):

Answers:

**1.Can we access native resources of mobile phones through this technologies ?**

Yes, you can by using javascripts.

**2. Do we need different coding to access different mobile operating systems ?**

Yes, there isn't one size fit all.

**3. Suggestions:**

Check the document of each individual mobile system. You will find the guidelines as well as examples.

Comment: can you please provide any sample code for access iPhone or Android or Windows phone alarm manager ?

Comment: can you please check this question and answer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727763/communication-between-android-java-and-phonegap-javascript/22014440#22014440). And i also posted a my question there.

Comment: @saw The example at the link you provided used PhoneGap. By the way if you want to work with devices in Windows Phone 8, you may want to have a look at this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211360.aspx