# Clickevents are not working in web view android

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

I have to create we application in android.

So what i done is that,simply created **raw** folder under **res** and put html files there.

All works fine but when i click a button that is put inside that web page nothing happens and the click event not get work.

Here are my codes.

**newfile.html**

```
<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type="button" value="Click me" onclick="openDialog()">
<script>
function openDialog()
{

alert("ok");
}
</script>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my java code,

```
webview.loadData(readTextFromResource(R.raw.newfile),"text/html", "utf-8");
```

**readTextFromResource function**

```
    private String readTextFromResource(int resourceID)

{
    InputStream raw = getResources().openRawResource(resourceID);
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int i;
    try
    {
        i = raw.read();
        while (i != -1)
        {
           stream.write(i);
            i = raw.read();
        }
        raw.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
return stream.toString();
}
```

Please some one point me why the click event not working !

Answer (score 10):

I am doing this type of things using phonegap. If you want to call native functions, use java script enabled web view. I am extends DroidGap in my MainActivity and my Login.html file under **assets** folder
in your Main Activity.java,

```
WebView webView=new WebView(this);
webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/Phone/Login.html");
setContentView(webView);
```

Anyway, if problem not solved, try adding this (all codes in onCreate method)

```
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.setClickable(true);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

If you want more about how to access Android native code through webpage [here is the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21826170/access-phone-alarm-native-resourcesusing-html5-reminder-app)

Answer (score 0):

When a `WebView` doesn't respond to a button, you can test a web page inside a mobile browser or a desktop browser with minimum width (adaptive layout). You will see how the button works when you click it. Then you can press <kbd>F12</kbd> and see what queries are sent in "Network" tab.

[image]

(If you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, you will see a layout of the page, then can click an element (the button that you look for) and see a code.)

If the button shows a picture dialog (take a photo, upload a picture), you should use `onShowFileChooser` ([[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29666844/onshowfilechooser-from-android-webview-works-only-once)).

```
val startActivityForResult = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { activityResult ->
    //
}

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    with(webview) {
        settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        settings.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
        settings.domStorageEnabled = true
        // webViewClient = MyWebViewClient()
        webChromeClient = MyWebChromeClient()
    }
}

private class MyWebChromeClient : WebChromeClient() {

    override fun onShowFileChooser(
        webView: WebView?,
        filePathCallback: ValueCallback<Array<Uri>>?,
        fileChooserParams: FileChooserParams?
    ): Boolean {
        // Check permissions, create intent.
        startActivityForResult.launch(chooserIntent)
        return true
    }
}
```

In case you have a JavaScript button, you can attach *JavaScript interfac*e ([[1]](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34978009/addjavascriptinterface-function-doesnt-work-on-api-21), [[3]](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/392603/Android-addJavaScriptInterface)):

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    with(webview) {
        settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        settings.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
        settings.domStorageEnabled = true
        // WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(BuildConfig.TEST)
        addJavascriptInterface(
            JsHandle(this@WebViewFragment),
            "Android"
        )
    }
}

class JsHandle(private var fragment: WebViewFragment) {

    @JavascriptInterface
    fun notify(notify: String) {
        //
    }
}
```

Your web page should have `javascript:` inside.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem also. I fixed it by just set the `WebChromeClient`. Put this line at the `onCreate` method.

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```