# onShowFileChooser() from android webview works only once

Tags: android, webview, android-5.0-lollipop, filechooser

I need to pick images from the device and upload it to the server. For the first time, when I pick the images, onShowFileChooser() gets called and everything works. But, when I try to click upload again, onShowFileChooser() never gets called. But it's working for non-lollypop devices. openFileChoser() gets called, whenever I click upload. Is there anything that I'm missing. Here is my code :

```
        //Needed for file upload feature
        vWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

            // file upload callback (Android 2.2 (API level 8) -- Android 2.3 (API level 10)) (hidden method)
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> filePathCallback) {
                showAttachmentDialog(filePathCallback);
            }

            // file upload callback (Android 3.0 (API level 11) -- Android 4.0 (API level 15)) (hidden method)
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback filePathCallback, String acceptType) {
                showAttachmentDialog(filePathCallback);
            }

            // file upload callback (Android 4.1 (API level 16) -- Android 4.3 (API level 18)) (hidden method)
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> filePathCallback, String acceptType, String capture) {
                showAttachmentDialog(filePathCallback);

            }

            // file upload callback (Android 5.0 (API level 21) -- current) (public method)

            // for Lollipop, all in one
            @Override

            public boolean onShowFileChooser(
                    WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback,
                    WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
                // Double check that we don't have any existing callbacks
                if (mFilePathCallbackArray != null) {
                    mFilePathCallbackArray.onReceiveValue(null);
                }
                mFilePathCallbackArray = filePathCallback;
                // Set up the take picture intent

                if (mTypeCap == IMAGE) {
                    Intent takePictureIntent = pictureIntentSetup();
                    return showChooserDialog(takePictureIntent);
                }
                //set up video capture intent
                else {
                    Intent takeVideoIntent = videoIntentSetUp();
                    return showChooserDialog(takeVideoIntent);
                }

            }

        });

  //For lollypop
    private Intent pictureIntentSetup() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {

            // create the file where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
                takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCameraPhotoPath);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
                Log.e("Failed", "Unable to create Image File", ex);
            }

            // continue only if the file was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                mCameraPhotoPath = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                        Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
            } else {
                takePictureIntent = null;
            }
        }
        return takePictureIntent;

    }

    //For lollypop
    private Intent videoIntentSetUp() {
        Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        if (takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {

            // create the file where the video should go
            File videoFile = null;
            try {
                videoFile = createVideoFile();
                takeVideoIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCameraPhotoPath);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
                Log.e("Failed", "Unable to create Video File", ex);
            }

            // continue only if the file was successfully created
            if (videoFile != null) {
                mCameraPhotoPath = "file:" + videoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                takeVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                        Uri.fromFile(videoFile));
            } else {
                takeVideoIntent = null;
            }
        }
        return takeVideoIntent;
    }

//For lollypop
    private boolean showChooserDialog(Intent intent) {
        Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        if (mTypeCap.equalsIgnoreCase(IMAGE))
            contentSelectionIntent.setType(IMAGE);
        else
            contentSelectionIntent.setType(VIDEO);

        Intent[] intentArray;
        if (intent != null) {
            intentArray = new Intent[]{intent};
        } else {
            intentArray = new Intent[0];
        }

        Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
        if (mTypeCap.equalsIgnoreCase(IMAGE))
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
        else
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Video Chooser");
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);

        getActivity().startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILE_CHOOSER_RESULT_CODE);

        return true;
    }
```

OnActivityResult of the activity:

```
  @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  //File upload related
            if (requestCode == NewsDetailFragment.FILE_CHOOSER_RESULT_CODE && (resultCode == RESULT_OK || resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)) {
                Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.container);
                if (fragment != null && fragment instanceof DetailFragment) {
                    Fragment currentFragment = ((DetailFragment) fragment).getCurrentFragment();
                    if (currentFragment instanceof WebDetailFragment)
                        currentFragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                }
            }

        }
}
```

onActivityResult of fragment:

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intentData) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intentData);
        // code for all versions except of Lollipop
        if (!Utility.isLollypopAndAbove()) {
            Uri result = null;
            // check that the response is a good one
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                if (requestCode == FILE_CHOOSER_RESULT_CODE) {
                    if (null == this.mFilePathCallback) {
                        return;
                    }
                    if (null == mFilePathCallback) return;


                    if (intentData == null) {
                        // if there is not data, then we may have taken a photo
                        if (mCameraPhotoPath != null) {
                            result = Uri.parse(mCameraPhotoPath);
                        }
                    } else {
                        String dataString = intentData.getDataString();
                        if (dataString != null) {
                            result = Uri.parse(dataString);
                        }
                    }
//                Uri result = intentData == null || resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK ? null
//                        : intentData.getData();

                }

                //  for Lollipop only
            }
            mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(result);
            mFilePathCallback = null;
        }
        else  {
            Uri[] results = null;

            // check that the response is a good one
            if(resultCode==Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                if (requestCode == FILE_CHOOSER_RESULT_CODE) {
                    if (null == mFilePathCallbackArray) {
                        return;
                    }
                    if (intentData == null) {
                        // if there is not data, then we may have taken a photo
                        if (mCameraPhotoPath != null) {
                            results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCameraPhotoPath)};
                        }
                    } else {
                        String dataString = intentData.getDataString();
                        if (dataString != null) {
                            results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            mFilePathCallbackArray.onReceiveValue(results);
            mFilePathCallbackArray = null;
            return;

        }
    }
```

Comment: What is "items" in your code ? may yoy share, i wanted to test it

Answer (score 38):

firstly, sorry to my english. you should return empty Uri[]{} to file receive

```
mUploadMessageForAndroid5.onReceiveValue(new Uri[]{});
```

### my code can choose take photo or local image:

```
private static final int REQUEST_GET_THE_THUMBNAIL = 4000;
private static final long ANIMATION_DURATION = 200;
public final static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;
public final static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE_FOR_ANDROID_5 = 2;

//JS
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

//set ChromeClient
webView.setWebChromeClient(getChromeClient());

//ChromeClinet配置
private WebChromeClient getChromeClient() {
    return new WebChromeClient() {

        //3.0++
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType) {
            openFileChooserImpl(uploadMsg);
        }

        //3.0--
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
            openFileChooserImpl(uploadMsg);
        }

        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {
            openFileChooserImpl(uploadMsg);
        }

        // For Android > 5.0
        public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> uploadMsg, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
            openFileChooserImplForAndroid5(uploadMsg);
            return true;
        }

    };
}

private void openFileChooserImpl(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
    mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
    new AlertDialog.Builder(mActivity)
            .setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if (items[which].equals(items[0])) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                        i.setType("image/*");
                        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
                    } else if (items[which].equals(items[1])) {
                        dispatchTakePictureIntent();
                    }
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            })
            .setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    Log.v(TAG, TAG + " # onCancel");
                    mUploadMessage = null;
                    dialog.dismiss();
            }})
            .show();
}

private void openFileChooserImplForAndroid5(ValueCallback<Uri[]> uploadMsg) {
    mUploadMessageForAndroid5 = uploadMsg;

    new AlertDialog.Builder(mActivity)
            .setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if (items[which].equals(items[0])) {
                        Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                        contentSelectionIntent.setType("image/*");

                        Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
                        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
                        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");

                        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE_FOR_ANDROID_5);
                    } else if (items[which].equals(items[1])) {
                        dispatchTakePictureIntent();
                    }
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            })
            .setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    Log.v(TAG, TAG + " # onCancel");
                    //important to return new Uri[]{}, when nothing to do. This can slove input file wrok for once.
                    //InputEventReceiver: Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
                    mUploadMessageForAndroid5.onReceiveValue(new Uri[]{});
                    mUploadMessageForAndroid5 = null;
                    dialog.dismiss();
            }}).show();
}

private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(mActivity.getPackageManager()) != null) {
//            File file = new File(createImageFile());
        Uri imageUri = null;
        try {
            imageUri = Uri.fromFile(createImageFile());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //temp sd card file
        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_GET_THE_THUMBNAIL);
    }
}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/don_test/");
    if (!storageDir.exists()) {
        storageDir.mkdirs();
    }
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    Log.v(TAG, TAG + " # onActivityResult # requestCode=" + requestCode + " # resultCode=" + resultCode);
    if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {
        if (null == mUploadMessage)
            return;
        Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK ? null : intent.getData();
        mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
        mUploadMessage = null;

    } else if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE_FOR_ANDROID_5) {
        if (null == mUploadMessageForAndroid5)
            return;
        Uri result;

        if (intent == null || resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            result = null;
        } else {
            result = intent.getData();
        }

        if (result != null) {
            Log.v(TAG, TAG + " # result.getPath()=" + result.getPath());
            mUploadMessageForAndroid5.onReceiveValue(new Uri[]{result});
        } else {
            mUploadMessageForAndroid5.onReceiveValue(new Uri[]{});
        }
        mUploadMessageForAndroid5 = null;
    } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_GET_THE_THUMBNAIL) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            File file = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
            Uri localUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            Intent localIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, localUri);
            mActivity.sendBroadcast(localIntent);

            Uri result = Uri.fromFile(file);
            mUploadMessageForAndroid5.onReceiveValue(new Uri[]{result});
            mUploadMessageForAndroid5 = null;
        } else {

            File file = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
            Log.v(TAG, TAG + " # file=" + file.exists());
            if (file.exists()) {
                file.delete();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: or just return null `.onReceiveValue(null);`

Comment: Thanks! However this causes a strange behavior that if user cancel the file selection (i.e. `resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELLED`), `null` is supplied to the WebView and cleared the originally selected image. How to solve this?

Comment: how do i handle this from a fragment?

Comment: anyone facing this on fragment?

Answer (score 14):

Faced similar problem i was returning boolean value in method onShowFileChooser, issue was fixed when i called super class method

```
        @Override
        public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
            //Logic to implement 
            return super.onShowFileChooser(webView, filePathCallback, fileChooserParams);
        }
```

Comment: I don't get it. Why would you ever override a method and then just call it from the override? Isn't that the same as if you had no method there?

Comment: //Logic to implement - 
implement the logic before calling super method

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed that. My apologies.

Comment: @ked, You saved my day buddy. Thank you so much :) Cheers!

Comment: If you look at the source code of ` super.onShowFileChooser()` in `WebChromeClient.java`, iit simply returns `false`.

Comment: @ked Can you please look at my question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56114296/how-to-extract-values-from-filechooserparams-when-onshowfilechooser-gets-calle

Comment: It crashed the time trying to run it the second time

Comment: that made it for me!

Answer (score 7):

In the onShowFileChooser() method you should return `true`, only if you are using the `filePathCallback`, which is the best way:

```
private ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback;

@Override
public boolean onShowFileChooser(
        WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback,
        WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
    // do whatever you need to do, to show a file chooser/camera intent
    this.filePathCallback = filePathCallback;
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                Intent intent) {
    // Check for your correct requestCode from your intent here
    if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
        // this is important, call the callback with null parameter
        this.filePathCallback.onReceiveValue(null);
    } else if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        // extract the uri(s) you need here
        this.filePathCallback.onReceiveValue(new Uri[]{result});
    }
}
```

Comment: `result` variable is unknown.

Comment: what is variable result? you did not declare it

Comment: The variable result is of type Uri, you have to extract the selected file Uri(s) from the passed Intent data. E.g. Uri result = Uri.parse(intent.getDataString())

Comment: Thank you for this code, it was very helpful. You can pass the parameter like this
`filePathCallback.onReceiveValue(WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams.parseResult(resultCode, intent));`

Comment: thanks a lot! this is the correct solution!!

Answer (score 6):

I had the similar issue that `onShowFileChooser` only works once. After few hours of trail and error and then I figured out using a simple experiment:

- Not invoking `ValueCallback` will result `onShowFileChooser` only works once. Below code only works once...

  ```
  override fun onShowFileChooser(
    view: WebView?,
    filePath: ValueCallback<Array<Uri>>?,
    fileChooserParams: FileChooserParams?
  ): Boolean {
    Log.i("blah", "<== onShowFileChooser ==>")
    // filePath?.onReceiveValue(null)
    return true
  }
  ```
- Properly invoking `ValueCallback` will make `onShowFileChooser` work every time:

  ```
  override fun onShowFileChooser(
    view: WebView?,
    filePath: ValueCallback<Array<Uri>>?,
    fileChooserParams: FileChooserParams?
  ): Boolean {
    Log.i("blah", "<== onShowFileChooser ==>")
    filePath?.onReceiveValue(null)
    return true
  }
  ```

so I just check all branches and make sure all properly invoking `ValueCallback` then the webview works as expected.

Comment: This is the only solution worked with me, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

Just set a null value:

```
if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
    handleImageRequest(data)
} else {
    mValueCallbackArray?.onReceiveValue(null)
    mValueCallbackArray = null
}
```

Comment: What is `resultCode` and where is it called in? In `onActivityResult`?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, the problem was I was expecting an OnActivityResult, but when you press the back button, this was not triggered.

The solution was implementing on onResume the following code, to tell the callback the answer was empty and being able to reuse it:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mFilePathCallbackArray == null)
        return;

    mFilePathCallbackArray.onReceiveValue(new Uri[]{});
    mFilePathCallbackArray = null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly same issue, But my use case is little different but my webview was loaded on a fragment as is in your code. first time the file chooser displayed fine on both Lollipop & pre Lollipop devices, but next time onwards it failed to display file chooser it self. The Reason being the I was not handled the onActivityResult in proper way at first time. My working code snippet is as follows for Lollipop:

```
 @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)

 private boolean onActivityResultLolliPop(
      int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode != SurveyWebChromeClient.FILE_CHOOSER_REQUEST_CODE 
            || mFilePathCallbackL == null) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        return true;
    }

    Uri[] results = null;
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (data == null) {
            if (mCameraPhotoVideoPath != null) {//if there is not data here, then we may have taken a photo/video
                results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCameraPhotoVideoPath)};
            }
        } else {
            String dataString = data.getDataString();
            ClipData clipData = data.getClipData();

            if (clipData != null) {
                results = new Uri[clipData.getItemCount()];
                for (int i = 0; i < clipData.getItemCount(); i++) {
                    ClipData.Item item = clipData.getItemAt(i);
                    results[i] = item.getUri();
                }
            }

            if (dataString != null)
                results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
        }
    }
    mFilePathCallbackL.onReceiveValue(results);
    mFilePathCallbackL = null;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: My issue is fixed. The reason for this was, webview was paused in onPause(). Hence it was not responding to button click

Comment: @AmandaFernandez how to fix this problem,please post your code,thanks

Comment: @Carl, I have already posted my code. In my case, In onPause() of the fragment, webview was paused and never resumed..So onShowFileChoser() was not getting called. Just check, what result code ur getting in onActivityResult(). The result has to be given to ur activity, which is then passed to FilePathCallback.  May be the result is not passed to ur activty. Check my onActivityResultCode().

Comment: @AmandaFernandez thanks for your answer.I have resolved this problem .in my case the problem in `onActivityResult()`,I do not handle the result

Answer (score 1):

Just let `onShowFIleChooser()` return `false`, will work next time

```
public boolean onShowFileChooser(){
... 
return **false**;
}
```

Comment: If you set `false`, then you will get an exception in onActivityResult when trying to call `mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(result);`.

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me (Kotlin, Jetpack compose)->

```
override fun onShowFileChooser(
        webView: WebView?,
        filePathCb: ValueCallback<Array<Uri>>?,
        fileChooserParams: FileChooserParams?,
    ): Boolean {

        if (filePathCallback != null) {
            filePathCallback!!.onReceiveValue(null)
        }
        filePathCallback = filePathCb

        return true
    }
```

In future I can upload or reject the file upload->

```
        if(onCloseCameraClick){

            filePathCallback?.onReceiveValue(null)
            filePathCallback = null
            showMediaPicker = false
        }
        else{

            filePathCallback?.onReceiveValue(arrayOf(uri))
            filePathCallback = null
            showMediaPicker = false
        }
```

Comment: Can you share the full code? Thanks!

Comment: filePathCallback!!.onReceiveValue(null)

this line is the key, BTW can be improved

 filePathCallback?.onReceiveValue(null)