# How to extract values from FileChooserParams when onShowFileChooser() gets called?

Tags: android, android-intent, input, android-webview, filechooser

We have a hybrid app that runs on Android and using webapp pages created in MVC.

We have 2 buttons - 
1. Document upload - Files, Gallery options should be available when this is clicked (no camera option)
2. Camera upload - clicking on this should trigger camera app in phone.

I have following code on mvc view :

```
<input type="file" id="uploadFile" name="files" accept=".pdf,.jpg,.jpeg,.gif,.png" style="display:none;" />
    <input type="file" id="capture" name="LnFImage" accept="image/*" capture="capture" style="display:none;">
```

in BrowserFragment.java, we have 2 Intents:

```
    Intent takePhotoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
Intent chooseExistingPhotoIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
```

when onShowFileChooser() gets called, how do I know if **takePhotoIntent** to call or **chooseExistingPhotoIntent** to call based on the button clicked on page?

Is is possible to extract value from FileChooserParams to determine which button is calling onShowFileChooser() ?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to extract `accept` attribute with `FileChooserParams.getAcceptTypes()` for more details have a look at [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams.html#getAcceptTypes()).

The `name` attribute can be extracted with `FileChooserParams.getFilenameHint()` [link to documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams.html#getFilenameHint()).

For `capture` use `FileChooserParams.getMode()` [as described in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams.html#getMode())

There is another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55449804/6723787) regarding this issue and the actual code that could help.