# Automatic bring application from background to foreground

Tags: java, javascript, android, cordova

I have an application in android, made in phonegap, running in the background. I would like to bring it to the foreground after a javascript verification. I found this link ([Communication between Android Java and Phonegap Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727763/communication-between-android-java-and-phonegap-javascript) ), Where i can call the method in java without problems.

I'm trying to change it to suit my needs. But isnt working.

Below is what I got so far:

**Class Main:**

```java
    public class HiveTaxi extends DroidGap { 

        private PhoneNumber mc;

        @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        super.init(); 

        mc = new PhoneNumber(this, appView); 
        appView.addJavascriptInterface(mc, "MyPhone"); 
        super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl()); 

        } 

    //other code....
```

**Class PhoneNumber:**

```java
    public class PhoneNumber
    {
     private WebView mAppView;
     private DroidGap mGap;

     public PhoneNumber(DroidGap gap, WebView view)
     { 
       mAppView = view;
       mGap = gap;
     }
     @JavascriptInterface 
     public void getTelephoneNumber(Context context)
     { 
       Intent it = new Intent("android.intent.action");
       it.setComponent(new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), HiveTaxi.class.getName()));
       it.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       context.getApplicationContext().startActivity(it);
     }
    }
```

**JS File** (line 491)

```
window.MyPhone.getTelephoneNumber();
```

**Error:**

```java
03-09 18:55:52.939 32758-32758/com.projeto.hivetaxi D/CordovaLog﹕ file:///android_asset/www/js/functions.js: Line 491 : Uncaught Error: Error calling method on NPObject. 03-09 18:55:52.939 32758-32758/com.projeto.hivetaxi I/chromium﹕ [INFO:CONSOLE(491)] "Uncaught Error: Error calling method on NPObject.", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/functions.js (491)
```